# Divide list into sublists with increments between values

Tags: python, list

I have a list `a = [39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45]`, and a position `b = 43`.
I want to split `a` into sublists with values that have similarities.

Every value in a sublist has to be either 1 or 12 apart (I can determine this number, `d`, in this case `1`).
So in this example, the new list should be:
`a_divided = [[39, 40], [42, 43, 44, 45]]`
Then I would need to choose the sublist which contains `b` resulting in `a_end = [42, 43, 44, 45]`.

Further examples:

```
a = [16, 28, 64, 76, 88]; b = 28; d = 12 
-> a_divided = [[16, 28], [64, 76, 88]] -> a_end = [16, 28]

a = [107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113, 114, 116, 177, 118]; b = 112; d = 1 
-> a_divided = [[107, 108, 109], [111, 112, 113, 114], [116, 117, 118]] -> a_end = [111, 112, 113, 114]
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to split the list into all sublists for this.  Find the position of the `b` elements and then get the following and preceding elements until you get to a difference that is not 1 or 12 on each side.

```
a = [39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45]
b = 43

result = [b]                       # start with b in sublist
p      = a.index(b)                # position of b
for n in a[p+1:]:                  # extend forward
    if abs(n-result[-1]) in (1,12):  # check difference with last
        result.append(n)             # add eligible at end
    else: break                      # end of sublist reached
for n in reversed(a[:p]):          # extend backward
    if abs(n-result[0]) in (1,12):   # check difference with first
        result.insert(0,n)           # add eligible at begining
    else: break                      # start of sublist reached

print(result) # [42, 43, 44, 45]
```

If you are required to break down the list into sublist, it can be achieved using zip() to compare each element with the next one and produce a list of break indexes (positions where sublists will split).  Then use these break positions as subscripts to the list and form a list of sublists.  Finally find the sublist that contains `b`:

```
breaks   = [i for i,(p,n) in enumerate(zip(a,a[1:]),1) if abs(p-n) not in (1,12)]
sublists = [ a[s:e] for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks+[len(a)]) ]
result   = next(sl for sl in sublists if b in sl)

print(result) # [42, 43, 44, 45]
```

*Although this is not as efficient as the first method, it is more generalized and could easily be adapted to support cases where there are multiple instances of `b` (or none at all) in `a`*